# jqueryUI droppable: How to execute function when element is dropped inside another valid droppable (+gets accepted)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a droppable, lets call it container.
Inside the container there are draggables, lets call them items.

Inside the container I want to add some text between each item and the next one (I managed to do that when "drop" is fired).

It is also possible to drag these items out of the container again. But **then I want to remove the text between**. Now to my question,
**how can a droppable(the container) be informed that a draggable(an item) has moved somewhere else?**

**Note**: the draggable can only be dropped into specific droppable areas, where they get accepted (otherwise they will revert).

I tried to figur out how to do this for quite a time, but it seems like there is no event, which is fired in this case. So how could I do that?